# Access Google Spreadsheets data through python

Tags: python

I am trying to output data from my ipython (jupyter) script into a google spreadsheet.

I am following instructions [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) and put this code into my python script :

I keep getting an error at this line from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials.

This is the error: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'openType'

I tried the following but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions??
pip install pyopenSSL
pip install pyasn1-modules
pip install pyasn1
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib

Comment: Please include a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue . Here is my code (example code for gspread module):

```
# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Book_name").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

And the solution is to manually reinstall pyasn1 / pyasn1-modules packages!

```
Try pip install pyasn1-modules -U or just reinstall pyasn1 / pyasn1-modules.
```

Found it here: https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/issues/10#issuecomment-360922132